# How to solve strange Haxe compiler error?

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, haxe, openfl

I don't think my syntax is actually bad here. Or is it? This is my first stab at OpenFL.

The Haxe is not compiling correctly? Am I missing a compiler directive? Do I actually have a syntax error in this function? *Syntax checker in Flashdevelop says no*.

Here's the command:

```
Running process: C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe "C:\dev\Haxe\TestOpenFL\OpenFLTest.hxproj" -ipc 2e4ace78-45b9-4868-a2dd-cf2c35265f44 -version "3.0.0" -compiler "C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe" -library "C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Library" -target "flash"
```

**src/Main.hx:32: characters 16-17 : Unexpected ;
Build halted with errors (haxelib.exe).**

```
function init() 
{
    if (inited) return;
    inited = true;

    //           \/ says this semicolon is unexpected. wtf 
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i ++)
    {

        var bmd = new BitmapData( 100, 100, true, 0xff0000ff);
        var bmp = new Bitmap( bmd);

        addChild(bmp);

        bitmaps.push( bmp );            
    }

    addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame );
}
```

Here's the whole script. I can't for the life of me figure out why it would error there. **If I comment out just the loop, it compiles just fine.**

```
class Main extends Sprite 
{
var inited:Bool;    
var bitmaps:Array<Bitmap>;

/* ENTRY POINT */   
function resize(e) 
{
    if (!inited) init();
    // else (resize or orientation change)
}

function init() 
{

    bitmaps = new Array();

    if (inited) return;
    inited = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < 200 ; i ++)
    {
        // Assets:
        var bmd = new BitmapData( 100, 100, true, 0xff0000ff);
        var bmp = new Bitmap( bmd);

        addChild(bmp);

        bitmaps.push( bmp );            
    }

    addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame );
}

private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):Void 
{
}




/* SETUP */

public function new() 
{
    super();
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added);
}

function added(e) 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resize);
    #if ios
    haxe.Timer.delay(init, 100); // iOS 6
    #else
    init();
    #end
}

public static function main() 
{
    // static entry point
    Lib.current.stage.align = flash.display.StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    Lib.current.stage.scaleMode = flash.display.StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    Lib.current.addChild(new Main());
}
```

}

Comment: I don't know Haxe specifically, but you should try declaring `i` outside the loop (so that there is no `var` in the loop). I've known some parsers to have issues with that.

Comment: Actually, see here: http://haxe.org/ref/syntax#for

Comment: Heh, ok. My syntax is completely wrong for an iterator then. P.S. I tried declaring the i outside the loop, which led to other errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing: have a look at the [Haxe syntax page](http://haxe.org/ref/syntax), it will help you for a lot of your futur problems.

Next, the **for** in Haxe is a bit tricky, it's kind of a **foreach**, so you use it like this:

```
for(myElem in elements){
    // loop here
}
```

Where elements implements Itarable (like an Array, a GenericStack or a Map). But if you want to increment a variable, you can *create* an Iterable by using the operator `...`. So, to take your code as an example:

```
for(i in 0...200){
    // loop here
}
```

Here, `i` will take as a value all the int between 0 and 200 (excluded).

Comment: On a side note, i guess since both ... and old fashioned loop syntax are ok by the Flashdevelop syntax checker, I wonder if that setting can change in FD. Guess that's another question altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Complete noob problem. Dove right in instead of reading the doc (which is the best way to learn, IMHO).

You can't use loops in Haxe. You have to use iterators.

```
for (i in 0...200)
{
         //do stuff
}
```

Comment: That's still a for loop, just not the "plain-old" c-style taste.

Comment: But doesn't an iterator rely on the type to determine the next() operator? while(setIterator.hasNext()){..} vs a loop that will execute the iteration regardless of the list?

Comment: Hm, not sure what goes on under the hood, but perhaps the ... operator is saying, "don't use the iterator" whereas e4x syntax for(x in y ) uses the iterator.

Comment: What I mean is, we generally think of "loop" as some kind of repeatation. There are several types of loops, and the use of iterator is one of them. The "plain-old" c-style for is another type of loop.

Implementation-wise, Haxe's `a...b` is typed as an `IntIterator`, but the loop will be compile to a plain while loop. But anyway, it is certainly a loop.